# Any issue connecting neutral and ground of bluetooth light switch to ground (or neutral)?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I'm installing a blue-tooth light switch that has live, bulb, neutral and ground. The light switch that's being replaced has 3 wires, black, white and exposed copper (I'm guessing that's neutral or ground). Should I just leave ground floating or join it with neutral when connecting it to the existing 3 wire set up?

Comment: You don't have enough wires to hook it up, but I think you already know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an old-style switch loop configuration, with no neutral in the box, just hot, switched, and ground.  This means that you'll have to take your "smart" light switch back and find one that does not need a neutral wire.

Comment: ....or route the wire X_X. Thanks for letting me know, looks like this project is going to have to shelved for a while.

Comment: Yes, running new wire will suffice. You can't run just a neutral though, neutral must be with the hots in the same cable.